# Cannot use bold and italic in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

I noticed that using triple-star to apply bold *and* italics doesn't work in comments.

For example:

```
this is ***some*** text
```

I would expect that to be rendered in bold and italics, as it does in questions and answers:

> this is ***some*** text

But in comments you get:

> this is `*`**some**`*` text

Comment: Example: this is ***some*** text

Comment: Funny, that example doesn't work anymore because the functionality is now ***operational***.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, times change :) [This works now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981).

Comment: This makes me ***happy***.

Answer (score 0):

We only support a limited subset of markdown in comments, and that one is odd enough not to include.

Comment: that was quick ;-)

Comment: Can't seem to find the FAQ on which ***are*** included...

Comment: Why is `bold italics` odd in comments, while `bold` and `italics` are okay? I did not understand.