# Can't use both bold and italic in comments, if using underscore for italics

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

Following [this old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16610/189165). This (bold+italics, when both bold and italics is generated using asterisk):

```
*when I'm uploading a transparent `.png` file (with alpha channel) **using Media Library***
```

works:

> *when I'm uploading a transparent `.png` file (with alpha channel) **using Media Library***

This (bold+italics, when bold is generated using asterisk and italics using underscore):

```
_when I'm uploading a transparent `.png` file (with alpha channel) **using Media Library**_
```

works, when put to post:

> *when I'm uploading a transparent `.png` file (with alpha channel) **using Media Library***

but [fails](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202037/site-icons-with-alpha-channel-for-self-hosted-wordpress-blog-network?noredirect=1#comment293406_202037) when used in comment. A bug or a feature?

Comment: Patient: it hurts when I do *this*. Doctor: then don't do *this*.

Comment: Markdown differences between different kinds of posts. Confusing users since the beginnings of SE

Answer (score 5):

Our posts and comments are formatted using different systems. Obviously, this bug affected the comment formatting system, known as MarkdownMini.

This will be fixed as of build 3737 on MSO/MSE, and build 2860 on other sites.